# Replace DIV content with another DIV in other page

Tags: javascript, html

I have 2 pages

page1.html

```
<html>
  <head>
     <script src="sorttable.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">     
        function PrintDiv(id) {            
           var divToPrint = document.getElementById(id);
           var popupWin = window.open("page2.html");

           // what here?    
           popupWin.document.getElementById('div2').appendChild(divToPrint);
           popupWin.document.getElementById(id + '_t').style.display = "block";
           popupWin.document.getElementById(id + '_t').setAttribute("class","sortable");

        }
     </script>
   </head>
        <body >
            <div id="divToPrint" >
                <table class = "sortable" id="divToPrint_t" style="display:none;">
                <tr>   
           <th>Edificio</th>
           <th>Tipo</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
              <td>E1</td>
              <td>T1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
              <td>A1</td>
              <td>Q1</td>
        </tr>
        </table>
            </div>
        <div>
            <input type="button" value="print" onclick="PrintDiv('divToPrint');" />
        </div>
        </body> 
</html>
```

page2.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="sorttable.js"> </script>
   </head>
<body>
<div id="div2">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I need that, when I press button, open new tab, with page2.html, and with the table in the DIV div2... with display block, and keeping class sortable for sorting.

How can do it?

Comment: What you want to do is called Ajax. There are numerous examples: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ajax

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you have to use Ajax for what you want to do